# Повторная отправка запроса из IdHttp при возникновении EIdReadTimeout

Tags: delphi, indy, delphi-xe5

В отдельном потоке имеется функция возвращающая ответ от сервера, но временами ресурс работает очень нестабильно и ответы от него приходят через раз, вываливаясь в исключение по таймауту `EIdReadTimeout` Упрощенно код выглядит так:

```
function TMyThread.GetDataFromServer(URLString: String): String;
begin
   ...
   try
     IdHttp1.ConnectTimeout:=30000;
     idhttp1.ReadTimeout:=30000;
     Result := idhttp1.Get(URLSring);
   except
    On E: EIdReadTimeout do
      begin
        ...
        Result := '{}'
      end;
   end; 
end;
```

Как сделать, что бы эта функция запрашивала сервер N-ное количество раз, пока не получит ответ, либо пока поток не получит запрос на Terminate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Может так вам подойдет?

```
var
  Done: boolean;
  N: Integer;
begin
  N := 0;
  Done := False;
  IdHttp1.ConnectTimeout:=30000;
  idhttp1.ReadTimeout:=30000;
  repeat    
    try
      Result := idhttp1.Get(URLSring);
      Done := True;
    except
      On E: EIdReadTimeout do
      begin
        ...
        Inc(N);
      end;
    end;
  until Done or (N > 5);
end;
```

Comment: Да, подойдет. Была такая мысль, но почему-то посчитал, что except безусловно выводит выполнение из процедуры. Спасибо!

Comment: он как раз и перехватывает этот "безусловный выход" обрабатывая или проглатывая исключение

Comment: вынесите настройки таймаута `idHttp` из цикла, и уберите присваивание `result` из `except`-а. И сравнивать полученный `result` не совсем хорошо (там видимо json будет). Лучше завести какой нибудь `done: boolean`, который присвоить `true` после успешного запроса, и крутить `while not done or (n > 0)`

Comment: @zed `repeat until` Вы серьезно? И зачем нужен аж целый `Integer`? Почему тогда не `goto`, лишились бы сразу лишней переменной?

Comment: Во-первых, условие цикла `while` было не верным и при `Done = True` он не останавливался. Во-вторых, для счётчиков всегда нужно использовать *знаковый тип*, тем более, что для его изменения используется функция `Inc` (или `Dec`) которая работает с интами. Т.е. производится типизация Byte <-> Integer и возможно переполнение Byte. Экономия на спичках может в итоге вылезти багом.

Comment: @zed, согласен. Вопросов нет!)